# LVL problem under WiFi only devices

Tags: android, android-lvl

Are there any known issues with WiFi only devices doing ServerManaged LVL license checks?

Comment: Effectively it is failing the LVL license check.

Comment: Cat, Check what the log says. Usually when debugging an app you will see informative log message about communications. If you can post that here maybe we can be of more help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not experienced any.

Note however the Google account using the LVL must be marked as a test account before being able to use the application.

Also if your the publisher Google account you cannot download your own app from the market.

If your experiencing problems with the system those two are probably the issue.

Comment: It's actually sporadic that customers are seeing this.  Perhaps 1-2%.

Comment: All communication for the system is done through the Android Market app. If they experience issues with your licensing implementation they should also be seeing problems using Android Market at all.

Comment: Turned out the user had clock issues.

Comment: @CatManDo Can you elaborate on the clock issues?  I have a user who reports the same problem - licensing works on cellular connection but not on WiFi.

Comment: @Dan Dyer User had his clock set correctly but timezone set incorrectly.